# How to automatically find that package installation fails?

Tags: r, cran

I would like to install old package from mran snapshot. I am using this command:

```
tryCatch({
  resp <- install.packages(pkgs = "https://cran.microsoft.com/snapshot/2016-12-05/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/car_2.1-4.zip", 
                           repos = NULL, 
                           dependencies = FALSE, 
                           type = "win.binary")
},
warning = function(e) {
  print("ITERATE - WARNING")
},
error = function(e) {
  print("ITERATE - ERROR")
})
```

I know that I can use packages like versions or devtools. tryCatch is here not by mistake. The question is if I can try/catch it somehow?

I know that I can check if url exists before or even download file like that:

```
tryCatch({
  download.file("https://cran.microsoft.com/snapshot/2016-12-05/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/car_2.1-4.zip", destfile = "car_2.1-4.zip")
},
error = function(e) {
  print("ITERATE - ERROR")
})
```

But it is not solution which I am looking for. I would like to identify that this function fails and then handle it somehow.

> install.packages()

Can somebody give me some tips?

Answer (score 1):

If you cant trap this I can only assume you are using Rstudio and not just R.

use `utils::install.packages()` instead of the Rstudio version.

My personal favorite way to do this would be.

```
##' Catch *and* save both errors and warnings, and in the case of
##' a warning, also keep the computed result.
##'
##' @title tryCatch both warnings (with value) and errors
##' @param expr an \R expression to evaluate
##' @return a list with 'value' and 'warning', where
##'   'value' may be an error caught.
##' @author Martin Maechler;
##' Copyright (C) 2010-2012  The R Core Team
tryCatch.W.E <- function(expr)
{
    W <- NULL
    w.handler <- function(w){ # warning handler
        W <<- w
        invokeRestart("muffleWarning")
    }
    list(value = withCallingHandlers(tryCatch(expr, error = function(e) e),
                                     warning = w.handler),
         warning = W)
}

 tryme <- tryCatch.W.E({utils::install.packages(pkgs = "https://cran.microsoft.com/snapshot/2016-12-05/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/car_2.1-4.zip", 
                          repos = NULL, 
                          dependencies = FALSE, 
                          type = "win.binary")})
```

Then tryme will have your error in it and this will allow you to keep on moving forward without a hard `stop`.

Comment: Awesome, Thank You! Could you explained me how you have found that RStudio changed behavior of `install.packages()`? It surprised me a lot.

Comment: Additionally when I am going to sources, from both usages I am going to utils package.

Comment: I mostly guessed. but when I typed install.packages and utils::install.packages to peak at the source I got different results. so I tried catching the utils version and it worked. I can only assume that Rstudio is doing it's own error handling to protect us from ourselves and that's why we are not able to detect an error on failure.

Comment: Please accept the answer if this is what you were looking for.